# remove_if equivalent for std::map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I was trying to erase a range of elements from map based on particular condition. How do I do it using STL algorithms?

Initially I thought of using `remove_if` but it is not possible as remove_if does not work for associative container.

Is there any "remove_if" equivalent algorithm which works for map ?

As a simple option, I thought of looping through the map and erase. But is looping through the map and erasing a safe option?(as iterators get invalid after erase)

I used following example:

```
bool predicate(const std::pair<int,std::string>& x)
{
    return x.first > 2;
}

int main(void) 
{

    std::map<int, std::string> aMap;

    aMap[2] = "two";
    aMap[3] = "three";
    aMap[4] = "four";
    aMap[5] = "five";
    aMap[6] = "six";

//      does not work, an error
//  std::remove_if(aMap.begin(), aMap.end(), predicate);

    std::map<int, std::string>::iterator iter = aMap.begin();
    std::map<int, std::string>::iterator endIter = aMap.end();

    for(; iter != endIter; ++iter)
    {
            if(Some Condition)
            {
                            // is it safe ?
                aMap.erase(iter++);
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that remove_if does not work?

Comment: I can't use remove_if to find an element in map, right? It gave an compile time error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope - it doesn't work as remove_if works by reordering a sequence, moving elements that fail the condition towards the end. Hence it does work on a T[n], but not a map<T,U>.

Comment: With C+11, you can use `for(auto iter=aMap.begin(); iter!=aMap.end(); ){ ....}` to reduce clutter. Rest is as others said. This question saved me some hair splitting just now ;-)

Comment: I see C++20 has `std::erase_if` for `std::map` ... if only I could transport my code into the future.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Almost.

```
for(; iter != endIter; ) {
     if (Some Condition) {
          iter = aMap.erase(iter);
     } else {
          ++iter;
     }
}
```

What you had originally would increment the iterator *twice* if you did erase an element from it; you could potentially skip over elements that needed to be erased.

This is a common algorithm I've seen used and documented in many places.

[EDIT] You are correct that iterators are invalidated after an erase, but only iterators referencing the element that is erased, other iterators are still valid. Hence using `iter++` in the `erase()` call.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this algorithm on the newsgroups and have used it in production code. We kitted it up in a utility function in our toolbox.

Comment: I'm confused; why would you use for(; ... ;) instead of while(...)? Also, while this probably works, doesn't .erase return an iterator of the next one? So it seems like the if (Some Condition) blog should be iter = aMap.erase(iter) to be the most compatible.  Perhaps I'm missing something? I lack the experience some of you have.

Comment: @Taxilian: The return type of `.erase()` depends on the kind of container you're calling it on. The `map::erase(iterator)` method returns `void`.

Comment: Note, in C++11 all associative containers, including `map`, return the next iterator from `erase(iter)`. It's much cleaner to do `iter = erase( iter )`.

Comment: @taxilian (years late) while() or for() would work, but semantically, people often use for() for iterating over a known range, and while() for an unknown number of loops. Since the range is known in this case (from the beginning, to **endIter**), for() wouldn't be an unusual choice, and would probably be more common. But again, both would be acceptable.

Comment: @taxilian More importantly: with 'for', you can have your iterator definition INSIDE the scope of the loop, so it doesn't mess with the rest of your program.

Comment: @sanchises I do understand that about for, of course; my confusion was that in this case the definition *isn't* inside the scope of the loop.  I think this has been adequately explained, however.

Comment: @Potatoswatter It is not also cleaner but faster and more memory efficient, since the post increment operator makes a copy which can be expensive in case of custom iterators. This is also the reason why you should always use `for(auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it)` instead of `for(auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); it++)`

Comment: @Potatoswatter are you saying use `for(; iter != endIter; ) { if (Some Condition) { iter = aMap.erase(iter); } else { ++iter; } }` instead of `for(; iter != endIter; ) { if (Some Condition) { aMap.erase(iter++); } else { ++iter; } }` ?

Comment: @athos [Edit: Yes, that's the advice of my previous comment.] This Q&A from 2009 is outdated. Please refer to something newer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter i don't get it.. do you mean in C++ 11 it's recommended to write `for(; iter != endIter; ) { if (Some Condition) { iter = aMap.erase(iter); } else { ++iter; } } `?

Comment: @athos If I were writing it now, I suppose I'd do `while ( iter != endIter ) { auto oldIter = iter ++; if (Some Condition) { aMap.erase( oldIter ); } }`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter i'm lost. what's the benefit of doing so? and what's the reason this is more preferrable?

Comment: @athos The question is phrased in the passive voice, "it's recommended." There's no universal recommendation. I think my last comment is the most straightforward way. It does involve two copies of the iterator variable, which loses a little efficiency as someone pointed out here. It's your call what's appropriate for you.

Comment: This solution is kind of confusing since stl doesn't support function erase returning next iterator.

Comment: Out-of-date for modern C++ (e.g. 20)

Answer (score 88):

### erase_if for std::map (and other containers)

I use the following template for this very thing.

```
namespace stuff {
  template< typename ContainerT, typename PredicateT >
  void erase_if( ContainerT& items, const PredicateT& predicate ) {
    for( auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ) {
      if( predicate(*it) ) it = items.erase(it);
      else ++it;
    }
  }
}
```

This won't return anything, but it will remove the items from the std::map.

Usage example:

```
// 'container' could be a std::map
// 'item_type' is what you might store in your container
using stuff::erase_if;
erase_if(container, []( item_type& item ) {
  return /* insert appropriate test */;
});
```

Second example (allows you to pass in a test value):

```
// 'test_value' is value that you might inject into your predicate.
// 'property' is just used to provide a stand-in test
using stuff::erase_if;
int test_value = 4;  // or use whatever appropriate type and value
erase_if(container, [&test_value]( item_type& item ) {
  return item.property < test_value;  // or whatever appropriate test
});
```

Comment: @CodeAngry Thanks--it always seemed weird to me that this didn't already exist in `std`.  I understand why it isn't a member of `std::map`, but I think something like it should be in the standard library.

Comment: Will be added in [C++20 for `std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if) and others.

Answer (score 10):

Now, `std::experimental::erase_if` is available in header `<experimental/map>`.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/map/erase_if

Comment: It's now in C++20

Answer (score 9):

For those on **C++20** there are built-in **std::erase_if** functions for [**map**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if) and [**unordered_map**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase_if):

```
std::unordered_map<int, char> data {{1, 'a'},{2, 'b'},{3, 'c'},{4, 'd'},
                                    {5, 'e'},{4, 'f'},{5, 'g'},{5, 'g'}};
 
const auto count = std::erase_if(data, [](const auto& item) {
    auto const& [key, value] = item;
    return (key & 1) == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is some elegant solution.

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end();)
{   
    (SomeCondition) ? map.erase(it++) : (++it);
}
```

Comment: This relies on it++ fully evaluating before map.erase(...) is called (which, of course, it does) _and_ it relies on map.erase(...) not invalidating any iterators other than what is erased. All of this is true. I just think it's worth spelling out in case someone unknowingly carries this pattern over to another container.

Answer (score 3):

I got this documentation from the [excellent SGI STL reference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html):

> Map has the important property that
>   inserting a new element into a map
>   does not invalidate iterators that
>   point to existing elements. Erasing an
>   element from a map also does not
>   invalidate any iterators, except, of
>   course, for iterators that actually
>   point to the element that is being
>   erased.

So, the iterator you have which is pointing at the element to be erased will of course be invalidated. Do something like this:

```
if (some condition)
{
  iterator here=iter++;
  aMap.erase(here)
}
```

Comment: This is no different to the original code. iter++ increments the iterator then returns an iterator pointing at the element before the increment.

Comment: But iter will not be invalidated since we then erase at the position of here

Comment: @1800INFORMATION: entering a function call is a sequence point, the increment side effect is evaluated before `erase` is called. So they are indeed equivalent. Still, I'd strongly prefer your version over the original.

Comment: It works for array or vector, but will cause unexpected result in stl  map.

Answer (score 2):

The original code has only one issue:

```
for(; iter != endIter; ++iter)
{
    if(Some Condition)
    {
        // is it safe ?
        aMap.erase(iter++);
    }
}
```

Here the `iter` is incremented once in the for loop and another time in erase, which will probably end up in some infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

From the bottom notes of:

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/PairAssociativeContainer.html

a Pair Associative Container cannot provide mutable iterators (as defined in the Trivial Iterator requirements), because the value type of a mutable iterator must be Assignable, and pair is not Assignable. However, a Pair Associative Container can provide iterators that are not completely constant: iterators such that the expression (*i).second = d is valid.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is no `remove_if()` equivalent.
You can't reorder a map.
So `remove_if()` can not put your pairs of interest at the end on which you can call `erase()`.

Comment: That's really unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

First

> Map has the important property that inserting a new element into a map does not invalidate iterators that point to existing elements. Erasing an element from a map also does not invalidate any iterators, except, of course, for iterators that actually point to the element that is being erased.

Second, the following code is good

```
for(; iter != endIter; )
{
    if(Some Condition)
    {
        aMap.erase(iter++);
    }
    else
    {
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

When calling a function, the parameters are evaluated before the call to that function.

So when iter++ is evaluated before the call to erase, the ++ operator of the iterator will return the current item and will point to the next item after the call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to erase all elements with key greater than 2, then the best way is

```
map.erase(map.upper_bound(2), map.end());
```

Works only for ranges though, not for any predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Iron Savior's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16597048/37558) For those that would like to provide a range more along the lines of std functional taking iterators.

```
template< typename ContainerT, class FwdIt, class Pr >
void erase_if(ContainerT& items, FwdIt it, FwdIt Last, Pr Pred) {
    for (; it != Last; ) {
        if (Pred(*it)) it = items.erase(it);
        else ++it;
    }
}
```

Curious if there is some way to lose the `ContainerT` items and get that from the iterator.

Comment: _"Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an upper case letter are reserved for all usage by the implementation."_

Answer (score 0):

[Steve Folly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/removeif-equivalent-for-stdmap/800984#800984) I feel the more efficient.

Here is another **easy-but-less efficient solution**:

The solution uses `remove_copy_if` to copy the values we want into a new container, then swaps the contents of the original container with those of the new one:

```
std::map<int, std::string> aMap;

...
//Temporary map to hold the unremoved elements
std::map<int, std::string> aTempMap;

//copy unremoved values from aMap to aTempMap
std::remove_copy_if(aMap.begin(), aMap.end(), 
                    inserter(aTempMap, aTempMap.end()),
                    predicate);

//Swap the contents of aMap and aTempMap
aMap.swap(aTempMap);
```

Comment: That seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I use like this

```
 std::map<int, std::string> users;    
 for(auto it = users.begin(); it <= users.end()) {
    if(<condition>){
      it = users.erase(it);
    } else {
    ++it;
    }
 }
```