# Erase-remove idiom with std::set failing with constness-related error

Tags: c++, stl, set, erase

Can someone help me out here?

Compiling this code:

```
void test()
{
  std::set<int> test;
  test.insert(42);
  test.erase(std::remove(test.begin(), test.end(), 30), test.end());  // <- Line 33
}
```

Is generating the following error when compiling:

```
$ make
g++ -c -Wall -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Wunused -Werror a_star.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h: In function `_FIter std::remove(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, _Tp = int]':
a_star.cpp:33:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:779: error: assignment of read-only location `__result.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = int]()'
make: *** [a_star.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In `std::set`, the elements are not modifiable. So, the `std::set::iterator` is also unmodifiable. From [this](http://www.tenouk.com/Module27.html) tutorial, section 27.3.2.1:

> In simple associative containers,
>   where the elements are the keys, the
>   elements are completely immutable; the
>   nested types iterator and
>   const_iterator are therefore the same.

Hence, the `erase-remove` idiom cannot be applied as is. You have to write a `for` loop, and use the member function `std::set::erase` inside it. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap) and this accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap/800984#800984) and another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap/800986#800986) for exact details, but in short, the loop is like the following

```
typename std::set::iterator set_iter; 

for( set_iter it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); /* blank */ ) {
    if( some_condition() ) {
        s.erase( it++ );       // Note the subtlety here
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Erase-remove idiom cannot be used with associative containers. Associative containers do not allow modifications of the entire container element through the iterator, which immediately means that mutating sequence operations (like `std::remove`) cannot be applied to them.

Answer (score 2):

As already said your code doesn't work because you try to modify a sequence inside an associative container, but you can't do this because this sequence is immutable. Rationale: set holds an ordered sequence, usually in a binary tree. If you were allowed to modify it, you could corrupt the container and the program would crash. Btw, it still can happen in some situations.

You can change your code to this:

```
test.erase(30);
```

Or use ArunSaha's (+1) code for more complicated criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, std::remove is never to be used with a std::set element.

As a set is not a pure array you have to use erase.