# C++ std::set::erase with std::remove_if

Tags: c++, stl, set, std

This code has the Visual Studio `error C3892`. If I change `std::set` to `std::vector` - it works.

```
std::set<int> a;
a.erase(std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int item)
{
    return item == 10;
}), a.end());
```

What's wrong? Why can't I use `std::remove_if` with `std::set`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erase-remove idiom with std::set failing with constness-related error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792600/erase-remove-idiom-with-stdset-failing-with-constness-related-error)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You cannot use `std::remove_if()` with sequences which have `const` parts. The sequence of `std::set<T>` elements are made up of `T const` objects. We actually discussed this question just yesterday at the standard C++ committee and there is some support to create algorithms dealing specifically with the `erase()`ing objects from containers. It would look something like this (see also [N4009](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4009.htm)):

```
template <class T, class Comp, class Alloc, class Predicate>
void discard_if(std::set<T, Comp, Alloc>& c, Predicate pred) {
    for (auto it{c.begin()}, end{c.end()}; it != end; ) {
        if (pred(*it)) {
            it = c.erase(it);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

(it would probably actually delegate to an algorithm dispatching to the logic above as the same logic is the same for other node-based container).

For you specific use, you can use

```
a.erase(10);
```

but this only works if you want to remove a key while the algorithm above works with arbitrary predicates. On the other hand, `a.erase(10)` can take advantage of `std::set<int>`'s structure and will be O(log N) while the algorithm is O(N) (with `N == s.size()`).

Answer (score 12):

Starting with C++20, you can use [std::erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase_if) for containers with an `erase()` method, just as [Kühl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24263441/9146385) explained.

```
// C++20 example:
std::erase_if(setUserSelection, [](auto& pObject) {
                                     return !pObject->isSelectable();
                                });
```

Notice that this also includes `std::vector`, as it has an erase method. No more chaining `a.erase(std::remove_if(...` :)

Comment: This should be the up to date answer!

Answer (score 8):

`std::remove_if` re-orders elements, so it cannot be used with `std::set`. But you can use [`std::set::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase):

```
std::set<int> a;
a.erase(10);
```

Comment: OK, thank you. But. Is it a problem? Let it re-order. Because of the complexity?

Comment: @herolover `std::set` is ordered, and the ordering is needed for its logarithmic look-up (it is a binary search tree). So it is related to complexity.

Comment: @herolover `std::set` elements order is pre-determined by the comparator function, you cannot change the order, the container woudn't work