# For versus while versus do loop statements

Tags: c

Is there a difference between `for` and `while` statements? Is it just syntax?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int cent_temp = 0;
    int fah_temp;
    while (cent_temp <= 20) {
        fah_temp = (9 * cent_temp) / 5 + 32;
        printf("%d degrees C = %d degrees F\n", cent_temp, fah_temp);
        cent_temp++;
    }
}
```

This means to me....

While the value of `cent_temp` is less than `20` then calculate `fah_temp`. Then increase the value of `cent_temp` by `1` and check it is still less than `20`; then go round the loop again.

Regarding the syntax:

```
printf("%d degrees C = %d degrees F\n", cent_temp, fah_temp);
```

This means `%d` means print to the screen, replace with a decimal number the value of `cent_temp` and `%d` means replace with a decimal number the value of `fah_temp`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int cent_temp;
    int fah_temp;
    for (cent_temp = 0; cent_temp <= 20; cent_temp++) {
        fah_temp = (9 * cent_temp) / 5 + 32;
        printf("%2d degrees C = %2d degrees F\n", cent_temp, fah_temp);
    }
}
```

My interpretation of the above is:
for `cent_temp` = `0` repeat while `cent_temp` less than `20` and then execute `cent_temp+1` at the end. So `cent_temp` `0` goes into the loop to calculate `fah_temp` and gets printed to the screen. Then `cent_temp` goes up by one then goes round the loop again. Here I've used `%2d` instead of `%d` to signify that it should have 2 spaces for a decimal number (and they line up when executed). Both codes will not execute if `cent_temp > 20`.

Similarly rearranging the statement in a `do` `while` loop has a similar effect and doesn't really have an impact on the result.

Does each type of loop have a different application?

Please correct me if I wrong!

Comment: You might want to have a look into a good C book. Most of them detail what the different loops do and specifically what the `for` statement exactly does (and that is indeed syntactic sugar). They also should detail where each statement is better suited. Write code readable by humans. Caution: The `do` loop is indeed different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you would use a `for` loop to iterate over a finite set of values, whereas you'd use a `while` or `do-while` loop to iterate while a specific condition or set of conditions is true.  In most of C's contemporaries (Basic, Pascal, Fortran, etc.), a `for` loop can *only* iterate over a scalar index:

Fortran:

```
      DO 10 i=1,10
        statements
   10 CONTINUE
```

Pascal:

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
begin
  statements
end;
```

Both of these snippets loop exactly 10 times.  The index `i` is initialized and updated by the loop automagically.  I'd have to go back and check, but I'm pretty sure you cannot write to `i` in the loop body.

C actually blurred the lines between a `for` and `while` loop by adding the control expression:

```
for ( init-expr ; control-expr ; update-expr )
  statement
```

In C, a `for` loop can iterate over a scalar just like Fortran or Pascal:

```
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
  do_something_with( i );
}
```

Or it can iterate over multiple scalars:

```
for ( i = 0, j = 0; i < 10 && j < 10; i++, j++ )
{
  do_something_with( i, j );
}
```

Or it can iterate over the contents of a file:

```
for( c = fgetc( in ); c != EOF; c = fgetc( in ) )
{
  do_something_with( c );
}
```

Or it can iterate over a linked list:

```
for( cur = head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next )
{
  do_something_with( cur );
}
```

In Fortran and Pascal, those last three loops would have to be expressed as `while` loops (which I'm not going to do, because I've pretty much exhausted my Fortran and Pascal knowledge already).

The other big difference between a C `for` loop and those of Fortran or Pascal is that you can write to the loop index (`i`, `j`, `c`, or `cur`) in the loop body; it's not specially protected in any way.

A `while` or `do-while` loop is used to iterate as long as a specific condition or set of conditions is true:

```
while( control-expr )
  statement
```

```
do
  statement
while( control-expr );
```

In both a `for` and `while` loop, the condition is tested *before* the loop body executes; in a `do-while` loop, the condition is tested *after* the loop body executes, so a `do-while` loop will always execute at least once.

In C, you can use either a `for` loop or a `while` loop in many circumstances:

```
while ( ( c = fgetc( in ) ) != EOF )
  do_something_with( c );

for ( c = fgetc( in ); c != EOF; c = fgetc( in ) )
  do_something_with( c );
```

Both loops do exactly the same thing; it's just a matter of which one you think more clearly expresses your intent, or which you think would be easier for other people to understand.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a difference between 'for' and 'while' statements? Is it just
>   syntax?

To me, it is just syntax.

From **K&R section 3.5 Loops -- While and For**, I quote:

> The `for` statement
>
> ```
> for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
>   statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> expr1;
> while (expr2) {
>   statement
>   expr3;
> }
> ```
>
> except for the behavior of `continue`.
>
> Grammatically, the three components of a `for` loop are expressions.
>   Most commonly, `expr1` and `expr3` are assignments or function calls
>   and `expr2` is a relational expression.

**Notes**

As user @chqrlie has mentioned in the comments, control statements like `break` and `continue` make the situation slightly murkier.

There are some situations where the modify statement is necessary in the loop body. For example [Erase-remove idiom with std::set failing with constness-related error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792600/erase-remove-idiom-with-stdset-failing-with-constness-related-error) (in C++ though)

**Example**

As an example, let us write a loop to print all the odd numbers between 1 and 100.

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= 100) {
  printf("%d\n", i);
  i += 2;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i += 2) {
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

**Opinion**

I am not a language expert, but in most situations in practice I find them transformable.

I personally prefer using `for` syntax because:

- loop control structure is in one single place (the `for` header) making it easy to read, and
- the loop variable (e.g. `i`) is not exposed to the outer scope.

Comment: That's an over-simplification. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Can you provide a counter-example?

Comment: @unwind which sort of counter-example you're expecting?

Comment: A case where what @Arun said isn't true. I don't think there is one, I believe the above transformation works all the time.

Comment: @unwind ok, technically speaking, an `init statement` is not part of a `while loop`, that is what i tried to explain in my answer.

Comment: @unwind an optional decl of a for-loop init has no direct counterpart in a while-loop. The decl and init must appear outside the while-loop construct. `for(int i=...` must be done as `int i=...; while(...`. The locality of `i` is different, is it not?

Comment: @WhozCraig If you are looking for something that has exact syntax as a for loop then...you'll have to use `for` loops ;-)
All we are concerned with here whether it'd ever matter to write an equivalent while loop instead. The locality, if it matters, 
can be overcome with an additional scope: `{ int x = 0; while (x < 5) {...; x++} }`.

Comment: @unwind I certainly concur with you the *logic* is equivalent as Arun described.   Likewise your example of including an enclosing scope is spot-on with full equivalence including covering object scope. *That* would make a perfect synonymous example to the for-loop Arun has in his final example. Don't think I disagree on the logic path; only whether the two junkets are synonymous. In your example, they are completely so.

Comment: @unwind: it is an over-simplification in case there is a `continue` statement in the loop body as the *modify something* part would still be executed in the `for` statement and would be skipped in the proposed `while` translation.

Comment: Well, `do..while` construct has some other idiomatic uses than the looping. Update: Actually I see @Lundin have mentioned them in his answer..

Comment: Note: Please use the correct terms. _statement_ is a well-defined term, which does not apply to e.g. the conditon, and may not apply to the "init" (whatever that be). The `for` allows for a _declaration_ or an _expression_ as _clause-1_ and requires _expressions_ for the latter 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(cent_temp = 0; cent_temp <= 20; cent_temp++)
{ /* code */ }
```

is 100% equivalent to

```
cent_temp = 0;
while(cent_temp <= 20)
{
  /* code */
  cent_temp++;
}
```

But a `do-while` is different since it puts the condition check at the end.

---

As for when to use which loop, it is a matter of style and therefore a bit subjective. The industry de facto standard style, used by the majority of all C programmers, goes like this:

- `for` loops should always be used when performing a known number of iterations. It is then considered the most readable form.
- `while` loops should be used the the number of iterations is unknown in advance, or when the loop is turning complex for some reason. For example if you need to alter the loop iterator variable inside the loop body, then you should use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.
- `do while` loops should be used for special cases where you need to skip the condition check the first lap of the loop, for example `do { result = send(); }  while(result == ok);`.

Comment: I'd rather extend the usage of `for`: If the three parts (initialisation, condition and advance to next step) are closely related, it is preferable. All these are not hard criterions, though. Most important is readability. `do ... while` is a completely different beast, as it has different behaviour. There is not corresponding `do ... for`.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah I agree. There's a good rule of thumb saying that the 3 expressions of a for loop should only concern themselves with the loop iterator and not with other, unrelated things (that's also a MISRA-C rule).

Comment: Good orientation for beginners (MISRA is worth reading the rationales for the rules, but forget about the rules themselves). It is like cooking: A good cook and a good programmer know when to bend the rules a bit. If you fail, both can result in a terrible product:-)

Answer (score 2):

I looked at my **Code Complete**  by Steve McConnell *(the bible)*.

Here is what you can read in chapter 16:

*A for loop is a good choice when you need a loop that executes a specified number of times. [...]*

*Use for loops for simple activities that don't require internal loops controls. Use them when the loop involves simple increments or simple decrements, such as iterating  through the elements in a container. The point of a for loop is that you set it up at the top of the loop and then forget about it. You don't have to do anything inside the loop to control it. If you have a condition under which execution has to jump out of a loop, use a while loop instead.*

*Likewise, don't explicitly change the index value of a for loop to force it to terminate. Use a while loop instead. The for loop is for simple uses. Most complicated looping tasks are better handled by a while loop.*

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of algorithmic for and while are not the same. Shortly, in algorithmic, for should be used when bounds are known and while when you don't know if the condition can be met or when it can be. For is to repeat something n times (n known), which is exactly the case of your example computation; a for loop should be used (don't you think what the loop makes is more clearly stated in the for loop ?). If you want an example of a must be used while loop, look at something like Collatz sequence. From a point of view of computability, for loops can always be transformed in while loops but not the converse.

From the point of view of computer languages it is now common to fuse both, in C for example, it makes no difference, only syntactic. But remember that in some other language that could be very different, for example in Pascal for loops are very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Source code is written not only to be compiled and executed by computers but also to be read and understood by humans.

A computer doesn't really mind whether a `for` loop, a `while` loop or a `goto` is used. On the other hand, a human expects different meanings for different structures.

- computing values over a known range of inputs is best shown with a `for` loop;
- reading a file up to its end is best shown with a `while` loop.

Choosing which structure to use is similar as choosing a variable name.