# Erase specific elements in std::map

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, dictionary, containers

I want to erase some elements in my std::map.
I wrote erase + remove_if technique which I always do with other sequence containers.
But it wasn't compile with map. Why?
And How can I do this job?

```
std::map<int, int> m;

bool foo(const std::pair<int, int>& p)
{
    return p.second > 15;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    m.insert(make_pair(0, 0));
    m.insert(make_pair(1, 10));
    m.insert(make_pair(2, 20));
    m.insert(make_pair(3, 30));

    m.erase(
        remove_if(m.begin(), m.end(), foo),
        m.end()); // compile error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove_if does not work for associative container. see [stackoverflow.com/q/800955/346366](http://stackoverflow.com/q/800955/346366) you'll find an equivalent

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Write it like this for map, since `remove_if` won't work for `map` iterators (it merely puts offending elements at the end, and `map` iterators don't allow for this):

```
template <typename Map, typename F>
void map_erase_if(Map& m, F pred)
{
    typename Map::iterator i = m.begin();
    while ((i = std::find_if(i, m.end(), pred)) != m.end())
        m.erase(i++);
}
```

or if you like one-liners:

```
template <typename Map, typename F>
void map_erase_if(Map& m, F pred)
{
    for (typename Map::iterator i = m.begin();
         (i = std::find_if(i, m.end(), pred)) != m.end();
         m.erase(i++));
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, after `erase` iterators can become invalid.

Comment: @Kerrek: actually I don't like it, and I never write code like this. An empty bodied for loop is pretty much always clearer when written as a while loop.

Comment: Well, it's certainly not the most easy to read code, but it's a cool demonstration of what you can do with a `for` expression, and it makes `i` local to the loop scope without extraneous braces. Personally, I'd write `{}` at the end rather than a semicolon, I suppose.

Answer (score 10):

"With other sequence containers" is your error - `map` is an *associative* container! In associative containers, elements are defined by their key (as opposed to their insertion order in sequence containers), and you erase elements *by key*:

```
m.erase(12);
```

Erasing by key value has the same complexity as lookup (e.g. O(log n) for map, O(1) for unordered map, etc.). Alternatively, you can erase by iterator in constant time. Erasing an iterator invalidates that iterator, but no others (again unlike in sequence containers), so if you want to iterate over a map, the typical idiom is this:

```
for (auto it = m.cbegin(); it != m.cend(); ) // no "++"!
{
  if (it->second > 15)  // your own condition goes here
  {
    m.erase(it++);
  }
  else
  {
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Because `std::map` is not "sequence container" :)
`remove_if` will try to put useless elements to the end of the map, but this will cause of violating of implicit data-structure (red-black tree in most cases) of the map. The implicit data-structure defines place of each element in the map, and that is why `remove_if` is not allowed for `std::map`.

You should erase elements from `std::map` one after another (or giving some interval) in loop.

**Somethin like this:**

```
it = m.begin();
while ((it = std::find_if(it, m.end(), pred)) != m.end())
    m.erase(it++);
```

Comment: Erasing from a map does *not* invalidate iterators other than the erasee.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I mean that after `erase(it)` `it` becomes invalid, and `erase(it++)` should be used as in answer of @Alexandre C.

Comment: Well, but that's not what you're saying. You're saying "after erasing an element, iterators of map become invalid", which is *very* misleading.

Comment: @Alex: Oh, sorry, never mind! I overlooked that the find only starts at the last-found position. I removed the comment. Mirhan: Sorry for that, the `it++` *was* necessary. Make sure to initialize it to `begin()`, though :-)

Comment: It's has too many comparation than Kerrek SB or Nim's solution. Am I misunderstand?

Comment: @Benjamin: It should be the same. `find_if` stops upon its first find, so you only traverse the container once, in all the posted solutions.

Comment: @Mihran I think last edit is right code. it++ is necessary. Initializing iterator too.

Comment: @Mirhan: I'm sorry, your first version was right, so I edited the `++` back in so as not to have broken code, and you also need the initialization to `begin()` -- hope that's OK! :-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB yes it should be initialized, but if so then it should be defined as well `std::map<int, int>::iterator it = m.begin();`.

The code I post before was just part and not full program, so it was ok.

Answer (score 1):

This idiom only works for sequence like containers - entries in a map (associative) cannot be re-ordered (the key doesn't change - so how you can you possibly expect to *move* an entry to some other position - e.g. end). The correct way to do this is to find the entry and remove it - i.e. `it = map.find(); map.erase(it++)`

Comment: He's not trying to remove entries by key; he's removing them based on an arbitrary function.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Yes I am. But I'm reconsidering the container I should use. Why am I searching by value in std::map? -_-a Anyway, the answer is correct. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

class foo 
{
public:
    enum CompType { GREATER=1, LESS=-1 };
    foo(int nVal=15, enum CompType ctype=GREATER)
    : m_nVal(nVal)
    , m_bGreater(ctype==GREATER)
    {
    }
    bool operator()(std::pair<int, int> p) 
    {
        if (m_bGreater)
            return p.second > m_nVal;
        else
            return p.second < m_nVal;
    }
private:
    int  m_nVal;
    bool m_bGreater;
};

void MapRemove(std::map<int, int> &m, foo &pred)
{
    auto itr = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), pred);
    while (itr != m.end())
        itr = std::find_if(m.erase(itr), m.end(), pred);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<int, int> m;

    m.insert(std::make_pair(0, 0));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(1, 10));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(2, 20));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(3, 30));

    MapRemove(m, foo());

    for (auto itr=m.begin(); itr!=m.end(); ++itr)
        std::cout << "(" << itr->first << ", " 
                  << itr->second << ")" << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But it wasn't compile with map. Why?

When using `remove_if`, the type of dereferenced iterators must meet the requirements of CopyAssignable. That is it should be possible to assign one value to another.

For `std::map<int, int>` the value is `std::pair<const int, int>` which represents key value pairs of map and which is not CopyAssignable. The reason for this `const int` for key is how map works internally as other people already pointed.

By the way you will get the same compilation errors for sequence container like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<const int, int>>;
```