# C++ default copy/move assignment operator for extern C structure not const

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, constants, assignment-operator

I have a `std::map<CXCursor, DeclarationContent>` from which I want to remove elements using `std::remove_if`.

`CXCursor` is a (typedef of a) struct in external C code (libClang) that I cannot / must not modify.

Error messages from clang++ 3.4.2 --std=c++11 :

```
stl_pair.h:170:8: error: no viable overloaded '='
stl_algo.h:1152:23: note: in instantiation of member function std::pair<const CXCursor, DeclarationContent>::operator=' requested here

extract.cc:34:8: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::remove_if<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const CXCursor, DeclarationContent> >, bool (*)(std::pair<const CXCursor, DeclarationContent> &)>' requested here
  std::remove_if(decls.begin(), decls.end(), noCodeGenerationRequested);

include/clang-c/Index.h:2137:9: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable:
  'this' argument has type 'const CXCursor', but method is not marked const

/include/clang-c/Index.h:2137:9: note: candidate function (the implicit move assignment operator) not viable:
  'this' argument has type 'const CXCursor', but method is not marked const
```

The code is basically:

```
std::map<CXCursor, DeclarationContent> decls;
// filling the map
std::remove_if(decls.begin(), decls.end(), noCodeGenerationRequested);
```

with

```
bool noCodeGenerationRequested(std::map<CXCursor, DeclarationContent>::value_type & v)
{ /* FUN GOES HERE */ return true; }
```

From reading the error message it seems that the implicit assignment operators are not const qualified, which is needed in case of a map (as it's key is always const).

<s>I could write a wrapper class around CXCursor that provides those assignment operators</s>, but maybe there is another way?

---

`std::remove_if` does not work with a `std::map`, see: [remove_if equivalent for std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/800955/1116364)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is not usable with `std::remove_if`, since `map::value_type` has type `std::pair<const T, U>`, but `std::remove_if` requires, that dereferenced iterator should be `MoveAssignable`. Use just loop, or probably `copy_if` in another container with negation of your predicate.

Or you can use [boost::range::remove](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/remove_if.html#range.reference.algorithms.mutating.remove_if.description), if you already use boost in your project.

Comment: Oh .. must have missed that when reading remove_if docs. Thanks a lot, you saved me from writing a wrapper that wouldn't have helped anything. For reference, I think I'll be going with erase_if which is presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16597048/1116364