# using remove_if for a map container

Tags: c++, stl, remove-if

I was trying to use remove_if template for a map container but I am getting compiler error for the template argument. I am unable to understand why.

```
int main()
{
  map<const int, int> intmap;

  intmap[1] = 1;
  intmap[2] = 2;
  intmap[3] = 3;
  intmap[4] = 4;

  auto isOdd = [&](pair<const int, int> it)->bool 
     { return static_cast<bool>(it.second % 2); };

  isOdd(*(intmap.begin()));

 remove_if(intmap.begin(), intmap.end(), isOdd); 
}
```

This remove_if is throwing compiler errors. Any suggestion to fix it?

Error message is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\utility(260) : error C2166: l-value specifies const object
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\utility(259) : while compiling class template member function 
        'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::operator =(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&)'
        with
        [
            _Ty1=const int,
            _Ty2=int
        ]
        maperaseif.cpp(29) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty1=const int,
            _Ty2=int
        ]
```

Comment: Please clearly state the errors you get.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap

Comment: `remove_if` ends up reordering the elements in the range. `map` enforces a particular order. Hence the 2 are not compatible. The details is just messing about with types and `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`remove_if` works by scanning the elements and once an element is to be removed, it remembers the "gap" that will leave (keeping an iterator pointing thereto) while advancing another iterator to find the next element to retain... it then starts copying or moving elements from the latter position to the former until it reaches `end()`.

That doesn't work for `map`, because you can't overwrite the `pair<key,value>` elements wholesale: the key values aren't allowed to be modified or the sorted-order invariant the implementation needs could be invalidated.

So, you'll need to abandon `remove_if`.  You could use a normal loop, being careful to save the iterator-to-next-element rather than attempting to advance from a just-erased iterator.  Lots of other questions about how to erase elements from a map while iterating, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234779/how-to-remove-from-a-map-while-iterating-it)....

Answer (score 2):

This little `erase_if` templated function should do what you want. (I didn't write it, just picked it up from somewhere - so credit to whoever did!)

```
  template< typename ContainerT, typename PredicateT >
  void erase_if( ContainerT& items, const PredicateT& predicate ) {
    for( auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ) {
      if( predicate(*it) ) it = items.erase(it);
      else ++it;
    }
  };
```

In your example, you would use it like this:

```
erase_if(intmap, isOdd);
```

Comment: I tried even that  
    namespace generic {
      template <typename ContainerT, typename PredicateT>
       void erase_if(ContainerT& items, const PredicateT& predicate) {
         for(auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ) {
           if ( predicate(*it)) it = items.erase(it);
           else ++it ;
         }
       };
   } 

    generic::erase_if<map<const int, int>, 
                    [&](pair<const int, int> it){} > 
                     (intmap, isOdd);
But this too fails to compile complaining about PredicateT should be a type.

Comment: @AwanishGolwara  `generic::erase_if<map<const int, int>, [&](pair<const int, int> it){} > (intmap, isOdd); ` is ***wrong*** . For free functions you don't need to specify type. Just FYI, if you need to know the type of your lambda, you need `decltype(isOdd)`. So, if you want to specify type, it should be `erase_if<std::map<const int, int>, decltype(isOdd)>(intmap, isOdd);`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `remove_if` on `map`, since its value type is actually `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, but it you look at [requirements of remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), you can see, that dereferenced iterator type should be `MoveAssignable`.

Just write loop, or use boost for example.

Comment: I don't see the connection between the 2 halves of that statement. Note that his lamdba takes a `std::pair<const int, int>`.

Comment: @BoBTFish look at requirements of std::remove_if.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply your original answer was wrong, just that it didn't really explain itself.