# Erase in a loop with a condition in C++

Tags: c++, loops, erase, erase-remove-idiom

Is there a better way to write:

```
for (auto i = container.begin(); i != container.end();)
{
    if (condition(i))
    {
       i = container.erase(i);
       continue;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

This code does what I want, but it feels like bad style.

How can I improve it?

My container is `std::map`, but a generic solution would be cool.

Comment: It might help to know what `container` is.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the [Erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: I wonder why such algo is not in standard lib as it is more generic than erase-remove idiom

Comment: @Slava Like an `erase_if` function?

Comment: if container is a vector, this algorithm will be horribly inefficient.

Comment: @NathanOliver right, I know it will be less efficient on a `std::vector` than erase-remove but will work on most containers

Comment: in my case it's a std::map but if you have a generic solution, it's cool :p

Comment: @RichardHodges I believe it can be specialized for vector and others which may have more efficient way

Comment: @Slava [`std::experimental::erase_if`](https://rawgit.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/v2/fundamentals-ts.html#container.erasure.erase_if) in library fundamentals TS v2?

Comment: this is considered idiomatic for associative containers

Comment: @cpplearner C++ really needs ranges, otherwise you have to create a new algo for any sneeze

Comment: @Slava: Alternatively, just use the ones built in: `remove_if` + `erase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `erase` + `remove_if`:

```
auto pred = /* lambda or something*/
container.erase(std::remove_if(container.begin(),
                               container.end(),
                               pred)
```

Comment: That's erase-remove idiom, but will not work on `std::map` which OP seems to be using

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw the comment. I think I won't delete my answer. Maybe in comments some discussion will start and OP will get his answer

Comment: @Slava Why does it not work?  `remove_if` requires a forward iterator(map has bidirectional) and `map` has an appropriate overload for erase.

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::remove_if` moves elements, `std::map` does not allow that

Comment: @Slava Durp.  Forgot about that.  Also I found a `erase_if`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to...?

It is always subjective, but one way is a traits-based template function suite with a consistent interface, using tag-dispatching to choose the most optimal algorithm depending on the container type...

The interface function could look like this:

```
template<class Range, class Pred>
Range& erase_if(Range& range, Pred&& pred)
{
    erase_if(typename detail::range_traits<std::decay_t<Range>>::idiom_type(),
             range, std::forward<Pred>(pred));
    return range;
}
```

which defers to the correct idiom for the container type...

```
void erase_if(erase_remove_idiom, Vector& vec, Pred pred)
{
    vec.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
                             std::forward<Pred>(pred)),
              std::end(vec));
}

template<class Maplike, class Pred>
void erase_if(equal_range_idiom, Maplike& map, Pred pred)
{
    auto first = std::begin(map);
    auto last = std::end(map);
    while (first != last) {
        auto& item = *first;
        auto& key = get_key(item);
        auto range = map.equal_range(key);
        if (pred(key)) {
            map.erase(range.first, range.second);
        }
        first = range.second;
    }
}

template<class Maplike, class Pred>
void erase_if(map_crawl_idiom, Maplike& map, Pred pred)
{
    for (auto i = map.begin(); i != map.end();)
    {
        i = pred(*i) ? map.erase(i) : std::next(i);
    }
}
```

Here's the complete code and some tests.

Writing code like this always makes me feel admiration for std-library maintainers. So many corner cases...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <map>

namespace detail {

    // The general concept of range_traits
    template<class Range>
    struct range_traits
    {
    };

    // Tag for performing erase-remove on vector-like containers
    struct erase_remove_idiom {};

    // Using equal-range to skip redundant comparisons in multiset-like-containers
    struct equal_range_idiom {};

    // Crawling through maps...
    struct map_crawl_idiom {};

    template<class V, class A>
    struct range_traits<std::vector<V, A>> {
        using idiom_type = erase_remove_idiom;
    };

    template<class V, class C, class A>
    struct range_traits<std::multiset<V, C, A>> {
        using idiom_type = equal_range_idiom;
    };

    template<class V, class C, class A>
    struct range_traits<std::set<V, C, A>> {
        using idiom_type = map_crawl_idiom;
    };

    template<class V, class C, class H, class A>
    struct range_traits<std::unordered_set<V, C, H, A>> {
        using idiom_type = map_crawl_idiom;
    };

    template<class V, class C, class H, class A>
    struct range_traits<std::unordered_multiset<V, C, H, A>> {
        using idiom_type = equal_range_idiom;
    };

    template<class K, class V, class C, class A>
    struct range_traits<std::multimap<K, V, C, A>> {
        using idiom_type = map_crawl_idiom;
    };

    template<class K, class V, class C, class A>
    struct range_traits<std::map<K, V, C, A>> {
        using idiom_type = map_crawl_idiom;
    };
}


namespace detail {
    template<class Vector, class Pred>
    void erase_if(erase_remove_idiom, Vector& vec, Pred pred)
    {
        vec.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
                                 std::forward<Pred>(pred)),
                  std::end(vec));
    }

    // Generalised key-getter for sets
    template<class V>
    V& get_key(V& v) {
        return v;
    }

    // Specialised key-getter for maps
    template<class K, class V>
    const K& get_key(std::pair<const K, V>& p) {
        return p.first;
    }

    template<class Maplike, class Pred>
    void erase_if(equal_range_idiom, Maplike& map, Pred pred)
    {
        auto first = std::begin(map);
        auto last = std::end(map);
        while (first != last) {
            auto& item = *first;
            auto& key = get_key(item);
            auto range = map.equal_range(key);
            if (pred(key)) {
                map.erase(range.first, range.second);
            }
            first = range.second;
        }
    }

    template<class Maplike, class Pred>
    void erase_if(map_crawl_idiom, Maplike& map, Pred pred)
    {
        for (auto i = map.begin(); i != map.end();)
        {
            i = pred(*i) ? map.erase(i) : std::next(i);
        }
    }
}


//
// The interface function
//
template<class Range, class Pred>
Range& erase_if(Range& range, Pred&& pred)
{
    erase_if(typename detail::range_traits<std::decay_t<Range>>::idiom_type(),
             range, std::forward<Pred>(pred));
    return range;
}

template<class T>
struct emitter
{
    void operator()(std::ostream& os, const T& t) const {
        os << t;
    }
};

template<class K, class V>
struct emitter<std::pair<const K, V>>
{
    void operator()(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<const K, V>& p) const {
        os << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")";
    }
};

template<class Range>
void dump(Range& range)
{
    auto sep = "";
    auto e = emitter<typename std::decay_t<Range>::value_type> {};
    for (auto& item : range) {
        std::cout << sep;
        e(std::cout, item);
        sep = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

//
// Test on various containers
//
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> some { 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0 };
    std::multiset<int> some_mset { 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0 };
    std::unordered_multiset<int> some_umset { some_mset.begin(), some_mset.end() };
    std::map<int, std::string> some_map {
        { 1, "mouse" },
        { 2, "house" },
        { 3, "mouth" }
    };
    std::multimap<int, std::string> some_mmap(some_map.begin(), some_map.end());
    some_mmap.insert(some_map.begin(), some_map.end());

    std::set<int> some_set { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };


    auto is_one = [](auto& x) { return x == 1; };
    auto is_even = [](auto&x) { return (x % 2) == 0; };
    auto value_starts_with_m = [](auto& item) { return item.second.substr(0,1) == "m"; };

    dump(erase_if(some, is_one));
    dump(erase_if(some_mset, is_one));
    dump(erase_if(some_umset, is_one));
    dump(erase_if(some_map, value_starts_with_m));
    dump(erase_if(some_mmap, value_starts_with_m));
    dump(erase_if(some_set, is_even));
}
```

Expected results:

```
0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0
(2, house)
(2, house), (2, house)
1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```

Answer (score -2):

All of these questions and comments are quaint, but they don't address the original question.

What was asked is, how does one tighten up the following:

> for( i = ...; some_condition( i ); ) {
>       if( another_condition( i ) ) {
>           erase( i );
>           continue;
>       }
>        i++;
>    }

And the answer is:

> for( i = ...; some_condition( i ); i++ ) {
>       if( another_condition( i ) ) {
>           erase( i );
>       }
>   }

Comment: This is missing the point: when `another_condition( i )` is true, and `i = erase( i )` is called (note: you dropped the assignment, but shouldn't have), it's important *not* to increment `i`. That's because `i` has already been updated to point to the next element.