# Erase all entries with given value from std::map using std::for_each

Tags: c++, lambda, foreach, stl

I have map where individual Colors are mapped to multiple Entities.

I want to erase *all* elements from the map with given value `e` passed as an argument:

```
std::map<Color, Entity> encodedColors;

void eraseAllByValue(Entity e) {
     for (auto it = encodedColors.begin(); it != encodedColors.end();) {
        if (it->second == e) {
            it = encodedColors.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

The above function works just fine, however: how can this be achieved with `std::for_each` or similiar STL construct? I am having problem with creating correct Lambda expression.

Comment: Checkout the example of [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) or search for _erase remove idom_.

Comment: C++20 offers [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if) for this, before that your solution is as good as it can be: [remove_if equivalent for std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap)

Comment: @Timo erase-remove idiom is great, except for containers on which you cannot use remove

Comment: The `std::map` and similar containers are the odd-balls when it comes to erasure, since the programmer had to write hand-rolled `for` loops, as opposed to calling an algorithm function.  I'm surprised this wasn't addressed earlier than C++20.